# Diagramming resources in Azure Resource Groups

Tags: azure

Can someone let me know if it's possible to Visualize network topology in Azure? For example, if I am able to visualize traffic flows using Azure's Logic Apps. Is there anyway to visualize traffic flows in Azure.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately this question (tool recommendation) is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only two of those:

1. http://armviz.io
2. https://github.com/ARMataTeam/ARMata

they are not exactly what you ask for, but well, nothing else even comes close (that I'm aware of), so.

Comment: Hi, I'm familiar with those two. Unfortunately, they're not that great..